# I think I found a search bug

Tags: bug, status-completed, search

I just did a search for some criteria, and got 60 some odd hits. Upon browsing to the bottom of my 15 results per page list, I click on the link for page 2. And now the .SE tells me that my search criteria returns zero results.

Searched for: pokemon stats

Comment: Yeah, I got the same on MSO. Try now?

Answer (score 3):

It was a temporary snafu that was fixed quickly once Shog9 got wind of it.

> Yeah a re-index ran a box straight out of memory, working on it now. – [Nick Craver](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/135201/nick-craver), [3 mins ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160100/a-new-search-engine-for-stack-exchange/162015#comment470855_162015)